# Can I use my own Java program as a command in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, java, ls

I've developed a Java program which does the same task as the `ls` command in Linux.

After developing it, I was thinking about using it as a command in the DOS prompt.

Does Windows allow this? If it is possible, then which settings do I have to change for it in order to get it working?

```
c:>ls 
the output of the program "java ls"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just make a batch file and [adjust the PATH environment variable](https://superuser.com/q/284342/48078) so as to include the directory, where your batch file is stored.

Comment: @ankur `ls` should suffice

Comment: C:\Users\SiyaRam>ls

C:\Users\SiyaRam>java ls
**"Error: Could not find or load main class ls"**  i am getting this error.

Comment: @ankur most straightforwardly: within the batch file supply java with an absolute classpath  (eg. `java -cp c:\bin\lspackagesrc\ ls`)